# AngularJS - Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please, help me!

My project use Angular, MVC6

this is the error when I start Debugging

```
> angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-%20Quotes
>     at Error (native)
>     at http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
>     at http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:43:174
>     at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:40:432)
>     at http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:43:236
>     at d (http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:40:432)
>     at e (http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:41:158)
>     at Object.invoke (http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:41:243)
>     at Object.$get (http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:39:142)
>     at Object.invoke (http://localhost:55050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:41:456)
```

Here my code:

**File app.js:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myQuotesApp', [
        'quotesService'
    ]);
})();
```

**quotesController.js**

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('myQuotesApp')
            .controller('quotesController', quotesController);

        quotesController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Quotes'];

        function quotesController($scope, Quotes) {

            $scope.quotes = Quotes.query();

        }
    })();
```

**quotesService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var quotesService = angular.module('quotesService', ['ngResource']);
    quotesService.factory('Quotes', function ($resource) {

        return $resource('/api/quotes/', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', param: {}, isArray: true }
        });

    });

})();
```

This is the first time I use angularJS, thank you

Comment: Make sure file order is correct

Comment: why are you using two different modules ?

Comment: Please post your index.html file in which you have set some view. Make sure the order of files (or no. of files included) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message states that the `Quotes` factory depends on osme provider `a`. But I can't see that dependency in provided code. Show the real code or fix that dependncy in your real code.

Comment: I use gruntfile.js and here is app.js


`!function(){"use strict";angular.module("myQuotesApp",["quotesService"])}(),function(){"use strict";function a(a,b){a.quotes=b.query()}angular.module("myQuotesApp").controller("quotesController",["$scope","Quotes",a]),a.$inject=["$scope","Quotes"]}(),function(){"use strict";var a=angular.module("quotesService",["ngResource"]);a.factory("Quotes",function(a){return a("/api/quotes/",{},{query:{method:"GET",param:{},isArray:!0}})})}();`

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you should specify dependencies as strings.

E.g.

```
quotesService.factory('Quotes', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/quotes/', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', param: {}, isArray: true }
        });
    }])
```

And so on.